# Hosting Nodejs Mongodb website with frontend but not React

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mern, netlify

I'm very new in `MERN` stack development, I made a blog website with backend used **`HTML` `CSS` `JS` `NODEJS` & `MONGODB`**. and I want to host in `netlify` and `heroku`.

Tried So many times but got error.

**My Github repo link :**
[here](https://github.com/reyaz-mra/blogshut)

Can any one completely explain how to host ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started with hosting your apps, try a newer generation app hosting platform where you just connect your GitHub repo and it does everything else for you.

Node.js and Mongo is perfect for [Adaptable.io](https://adaptable.io). The free tier includes a Mongo database. Here's the guide to [deploying a Node.js App with MongoDB](https://adaptable.io/docs/app-guides/deploy-nodejs-app). You could also try [Render](https://render.com) but they don't have MongoDB.